# Como somar valores após filtrado no Django?

Tags: query, django, view, template, sum

Aqui está meu loop (em meu template.html):

```
{% for item in filter.qs %}
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ item.id }}</th>
    <td>{{ item.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.data|date:"d, F" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.tipo_pgto}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.mes }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.entrada }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.valor}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

A variavel {{ item.valor }} contem um valor decimal. Como posso fazer a soma delas (uma vez que é um loop) e colocar o resultado em outro lugar no meu documento html? Seria melhor usar Javascript ou teria algum jeito de fazer uma lógica dentro da view.py e criar uma variavel de armazenamento temporario e usa-la no template.py?

Answer (score -4):

Olá
Você pode usar as filter e tags do django, caso queira adicionar um valor a sua variável que está no loop veja a filter:add
segue exemplo: {{value|add:"2"}}.
Ou você pode criar suas próprias filter que eu recomendo.
Segue referência:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/